# SSL on my website hosted on GCP need an action

Tags: ssl

I've installed bitnami WordPress on GCP and issued SSL certificate via SSH. and was everyting ok till today.

Could anyone help and advice..

what shall I do

https://www.careersar.com/

Thank you

Remaz

Comment: Your **certificate expired** at 04:27:35 UTC today, about 8 hours before you posted this Q. Replace it with one that is not expired; if you used certbot to get it (which is NOT the only way to get a LetsEncrypt cert) just running `certbot renew` may be sufficient. Remeber LE certs are only valid for 90 days and you should normally have a process, either automatic or manual, to renew them at intervals of 75 days or less.

Comment: HI, How I do that...
am using VM for my website and hosted @ GCP means using SSH server..to enter any command. So, kindly advice. thanks

Comment: It depends on how you obtained the cert in the first place. _If_ you used certbot, _and_ did so correctly, as I said just running `certbot renew` (as the correct user and maybe with PATH tweaked) _should_ do a renewal automatically -- that's basically what certbot is designed for. Otherwise, you need to either understand what you did (i.e. not just cut&paste one of a billion 100th-copy blogs), or describe what you did in enough detail for us to understand.